# How do I delete from a binary search tree in Lisp

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket, binary-search-tree

How can I delete a node from a BST?

I need an algorithm to do that in Dr. Scheme.

Comment: That is completely a question of the implementation.  How do you represent the BST?

Comment: Might want to tag this with scheme and dr-scheme and homework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically toss the BST you have now, and create a new one sans the element.

You can do this by recursively descending the tree. If your item is less than the root datum, create a BST whose root and greater-than branch is copied from what you have now, but whose less-than branch is the result from a recursive call.

It's very similar to how you add a node, but when you get to the one you were searching for, merge the two BSTs below it and return the result.  There are surely existing questions about how to do that already.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your binary search tree uses straight forward cons cells with content only at the leaves, and assuming you are working on a homework assignment:
You can use `set-car!` or `set-cdr!` to change the content of a cons cell.

Comment: Cons cells in racket are immutable.

Comment: mcons, set-mcar! and set-mcdr then for R6RS

Comment: Cons cells are immutable in Racket, not in R6RS (including the racket implementation of R6RS).  But in general it is better to avoid these kind of side effects -- or if you have to, then a specific struct is better than butchering cons cells.