# Deleting an element from a BST in scheme

Tags: scheme, binary-tree

I can't seem to figure out how to delete an element from the BST. This is my code

```
(define remove (lambda (x t)
       (if  (< x (car t)) (list (car t) (remove x (cadr t)) (caddr t))
             (if (> x (car t)) (list (car t) (cadr t) (remove x (caddr t)))
                   (if (not(and (null? (cadr t)) (null? (caddr t)))) 
                       (let ((r (minimum (caddr t)))) ((remove r t) (set-car! t r))) 
                       (list '() (cadr t) (caddr t)))))))
```

Minimum returns the minimum value in the tree. 
If I try to delete an element that's not a leaf, it goes into an infinite loop. How can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374530/how-do-i-delete-from-a-binary-search-tree-in-lisp/4383580).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your biggest problem lies in this section:

```
((remove r t) (set-car! t r))
```

You are removing `r` from `t`, but you should really be removing `r` from the right subtree of `t`. I'm not sure why you are using mutability/setting, either; I think it complicates things in what could easily be a non-side effecting function. I would try something like:

```
(list r (cadr t) (remove r (caddr t)))
```

I also have to admit that I'm a bit confused about your intent with the last line. What are you using the empty list for?

Comment: Just to clarify, removing r from t rather than its right subtree is probably what is causing the infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can take a look here for the whole implementation of BST in scheme:

- http://en.literateprograms.org/Binary_tree_(Scheme)

It is very well documented and would give you a bit of insight about the way you can structure the code to be easy to read and debug. Especially, it treats leaf and node (non-leaf) removals separately.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it, but I would really like to hear any insight about why my code isn't working. It's a little frustrating especially that I've just started learning Scheme.

Comment: Agree - maybe what I wanted to say is: try to separate your code into functions that work simpler, so you can test whether they work correctly. This is similar to what they've done on the page I linked to - you don't have to do it the same way they did it, but you can separate it into `BST-remove` which calls `BST-leaf-remove` and `BST-node-remove`. This helps it understand the code and then finding the issue, as it's far easier that way.